# Accessing A File Inside Class Library Referenced By Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

My web application is referencing a class library project and in that class library project, I need to read a file. How do I get the absolute file path? 
I am using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(~relativePath)` for files inside the web application but that does not apply to the class project.

Should I change the "Copy To Output" and "Build Action" options of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(~/)` result from web project to class library first then work from there.

Or if class dll is in project folder (like ~/bin), get class library location
`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` and use that.